# r.serialize is not a function

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, phantom

I encountered an issue while signing the transaction from the Phantom wallet. When attempting to sign the instructions.

**error:
There was an error making the request: TypeError: r.serialize is not a function
at wc.signAndSendTransaction (inpage.js:26:35614)**

```
const signature = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(
  instructions[0]
);
console.log("---> signature: ", signature);
await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide more code?
probably more context is needed to find the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signAndSend of phantom expects a Transaction not an instruction.
You need to create a transaction and add your instruction.

The error most likely means that phantom is trying to serialize you transaction, but you are not passing in a transaction.

See phantom docs here:
https://docs.phantom.app/solana/sending-a-transaction

Also I would recommend looking into the solana wallet adapter which would support all wallets.